# How could I drag a marker, and get the lon/lat

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers and I have already found the implementation of dragging a marker, but there's no documentation about how to return the dragged position. I've tried this:

```js
drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors, {
  autoActivate: true,
  onComplete: function () {
    alert('hello')
  }
});
```

It doesn't return which marker was dragged so I can't get its longitude or latitude after dragging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually [the official documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DragFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature.onComplete) clearly states that the first argument to the `onComplete` callback is the affected feature. You can easily inspect its features in the handler.

For an example go to http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/drag-feature.html, open your browser's JS console and execute this snippet:

```js
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors, {
  autoActivate: true,
  onComplete: function (feature) {
    alert('x=' + feature.geometry.x + ', y=' + feature.geometry.x);
  }
}));
```

Then add a point and try dragging it.